# cron.php being constantly deleted

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a problem with a WordPress installation (even a fresh one), one and only one server. The cron.php file is being deleted in a random time. The site had an infection but it was reinstalled freshly. I have moved it a another server and this does not occur. Can this be a server side issue, or a specific configuration problem or what? Did not run into similar problem anywhere.

Comment: Which cron.php file? wp-includes/cron.php? /wp-cron.php?

Comment: cron.php as in wp-includes/cron.php, can't edit the question yet to change it.

Comment: WordPress itself has no CODE that will delete `wp-includes/cron.php` file. So this is definitely your server issue.

Comment: @Fayaz thats what I was trying to explain them, but the hosting insists its WordPress itself. Refering to FTP logs (why?!). Just wanted to confirm this if anyone actually run into such problem.

Comment: "**The site had an infection but it was reinstalled freshly:**" may be you've missed something. To be honest, there are many good hosts, so if that one server is creating issue, why don't you take a new server or a new host all together?

Comment: Also, it's very important that you find the root of the **infection**. Sometimes hacking / malware appears from FTP software as well. Not to mention, **FTP** itself is not secure. Use **SFTP** or **FTPS** and remove all old FTP access.

Comment: I am using SFTP. The whole thing was removed (DB, server files). The only thing I do not have access to are emails. So on a "clean" host it should not appear but they say WordPress deletes the file.... sure. Suggested hosting change to client. Thanks for your help @Fayaz!